Do PCF cloud foundry customer monitor application using SLOs?
Does anyone in the community comment on whether customers using cloud foundry for app deployment use SLO(Service level objectives) on the metrics generated by application like RED metrics? Looking for best practices from community using CF. Or are most customers are not yet using SLOs?
